# Start chapter text at particular place on page

Tags: sectioning, formatting, positioning, memoir, chapters

In a book whose layout I’m trying to emulate in `memoir`,
no matter how long the chapter title is
(they’re all two, three, or rarely four lines long)
the chapter text begins the same three inches from the top of the page.

I’m guessing the best way to achieve this
involves doing something clever with `\afterchaptertitle`,
but I cannot work out what.

My current chapter-style code is approximately this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}

\setstocksize{9in}{6in}
\settrimmedsize{\stockheight}{\stockwidth}{*}
\medievalpage[12]
\checkandfixthelayout

\makechapterstyle{unexpected}{%
  \renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\normalfont\Huge\centering\OnehalfSpacing}
  \renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\chapnamefont}
  \renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\chapnamefont}
  \setlength\beforechapskip{-\baselineskip}
  \setlength{\midchapskip}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\printchapternum}{\chapnumfont\NumToName{\thechapter}}
%  \renewcommand{\afterchaptertitle}{%
%    % what do I do here?
%  }
}
\chapterstyle{unexpected}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{The Unreasonable Length of\\This Book's Chapter Titles}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document`) that we could compile that shows your problem. BTW what is `\gingerfont`, I don't know or have it?

Comment: @PeterWilson, done. `\gingerfont` is from the actual code (referring to RM Ginger) and has been removed from the MWE.

Comment: given: the chapter text starts 3in from the top of the page, regardless of the length of the title.  unknown: is the distance from (1) the base of the title always the same distance from the top of the text, (2) the top of the title always the same distance from the top of the page, (3) the title is "centered" vertically between the top of the page and the top of the text, or (4) something else?

Comment: (2), the title always starts at the top of the page, and the gap between title and text varies. (Except for the font, the MWE mimics the original nicely.)